# Plese help me to express this Jacobian determinant $\frac{ \partial (x,y) }{ \partial (u,v) }$ only using u and v

Tags: derivatives, determinant, partial-derivative, jacobian

We define u and v as
$$u=\frac{2x}{x+y+1}$$
$$v=\frac{2y}{x+y+1}$$

I'm trying to get  Jacobian determinant　$\frac{ \partial (x,y) }{ \partial (u,v) }$ and express it only using $u$ and $v$.

---

What I have tried

$$x=\frac{-uy-u}{u-2}=-\frac{2y}{v^2}$$
$$y=-\frac{2x}{u^2}=\frac{-vx-v}{v-2}$$
$$\frac{ \partial x }{ \partial u }=\frac{2y+2}{(u-2)^2}$$
$$\frac{ \partial y }{ \partial u }=-\frac{2x}{u^2}$$
$$\frac{ \partial x }{ \partial v }=\frac{2y}{v^2}$$
$$\frac{ \partial y }{ \partial v }=-\frac{2x+2}{(v-2)^2}$$

But even if you calculate the determinant with these values, it end up with result below and fail to cancel x and y out.

$$\frac{-16yu^2x+64yux-64yx+4yu^2v^2+16yuxv^2-16yxv^2+16yu^2xv-64yuxv+64yxv+4u^2xv^2+4u^2v^2}{u^2v^2\left(u-2\right)^2\left(v-2\right)^2}$$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you first express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ only?

Comment: What happens if you calculate $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}$ first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}$ first

$$\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = \begin{vmatrix} \frac{2}{x+y+1} - \frac{2x}{(x+y+1)^2} & \frac{-2x}{(x+y+1)^2} \\ \frac{-2y}{(x+y+1)^2} & \frac{2}{x+y+1}-\frac{2y}{(x+y+1)^2} \\ \end{vmatrix} = \frac{4}{(x+y+1)^3}$$

Then notice that

$$u+v = 2-\frac{2}{x+y+1} \implies x+y+1 = \frac{2}{2-u-v}$$

which means

$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \frac{(x+y+1)^3}{4} = \frac{2}{(2-u-v)^3}$$

Comment: Long story short, solving for $x$ and $y$ explicitly is costly and, more importantly, irrelevant if the goal is just the Jacobian.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to confirm if we can simply take the reciprocal of result from the Jacobian.